# How can I adapt the sms user consent api to my own compose code?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to receive a 4-digit sms sent to the phone that the user enters and fill it in 4 boxes, and for this I found a very good example of the sms user consent api, but this example consists of a single screen and was not written in composite, so I did not know how to adapt it to my own code because all of a sudden I I have many screens and normally I need to receive the sms code on the screen where I receive the sms code.

**Here are the codes I found on the internet:**

**BroadCastRecevier.kt**

```
  import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
  import android.content.Context
  import android.content.Intent
  import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SmsRetriever
  import com.google.android.gms.common.api.CommonStatusCodes
  import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status

class SmsBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    lateinit var smsBroadcastReceiverListener: SmsBroadcastReceiverListener

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

        if (intent?.action == SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION) {

            val extras = intent.extras
            val smsRetrieverStatus = extras?.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_STATUS) as Status

            when (smsRetrieverStatus.statusCode) {
                CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS -> {
                    extras.getParcelable<Intent>(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_CONSENT_INTENT).also {
                        smsBroadcastReceiverListener.onSuccess(it)
                    }
                }

                CommonStatusCodes.TIMEOUT -> {
                    smsBroadcastReceiverListener.onFailure()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    interface SmsBroadcastReceiverListener {
        fun onSuccess(intent: Intent?)
        fun onFailure()
    }
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SmsRetriever
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var smsBroadcastReceiver: SmsBroadcastReceiver

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        startSmsUserConsent()
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        registerToSmsBroadcastReceiver()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        unregisterReceiver(smsBroadcastReceiver)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        when (requestCode) {
            REQ_USER_CONSENT -> {
                if ((resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) && (data != null)) {
                    //That gives all message to us. We need to get the code from inside with regex
                    val message = data.getStringExtra(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_SMS_MESSAGE)
                    val code = message?.let { fetchVerificationCode(it) }

                    etVerificationCode.setText(code)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun startSmsUserConsent() {
        SmsRetriever.getClient(this).also {
            //We can add user phone number or leave it blank
            it.startSmsUserConsent(null)
                    .addOnSuccessListener {
                        Log.d(TAG, "LISTENING_SUCCESS")
                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener {
                        Log.d(TAG, "LISTENING_FAILURE")
                    }
        }
    }

    private fun registerToSmsBroadcastReceiver() {
        smsBroadcastReceiver = SmsBroadcastReceiver().also {
            it.smsBroadcastReceiverListener = object : SmsBroadcastReceiver.SmsBroadcastReceiverListener {
                override fun onSuccess(intent: Intent?) {
                    intent?.let { context -> startActivityForResult(context, REQ_USER_CONSENT) }
                }

                override fun onFailure() {
                }
            }
        }

        val intentFilter = IntentFilter(SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION)
        registerReceiver(smsBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter)
    }

    private fun fetchVerificationCode(message: String): String {
        return Regex("(\\d{6})").find(message)?.value ?: ""
    }

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "SMS_USER_CONSENT"

        const val REQ_USER_CONSENT = 100
    }
}
```

**Hear is my example compose screen:**

```
@Composable
fun VerificationPhoneCodeScreen(
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    state: VerificationPhoneCodeScreenState,
    onChangeOtpValue: (String) -> Unit,
    setError: (Boolean) -> Unit,
    verificationSmsCode: (VerifySmsCodeRequestModel) -> Unit,
    addLeadingZeros: (Int) -> Int
) {


   
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            BackPopUp(
                navController = navHostController,
                route = RegisterScreen.SignUpUserFormScreen.route
            )
        },
        backgroundColor = Color.Transparent
    ) {

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top
        ) {

            Text(
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp),
                text = Enter your sms code the below,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle1
            )

            OtpTextField(
                otpText = state.otpValue,
                otpVerificationStatus = state.otpVerificationStatus,
                onOtpTextChange = { value, otpInputFilled ->
                    if (!state.isLoading) {
                        onChangeOtpValue(value)

                        if (otpInputFilled) {
                            //  val code = value.toInt()

                            verificationSmsCode(VerifySmsCodeRequestModel(code = 1234))
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
}
```

I only shared this much to shorten the code. On the previous screen, the user enters his phone number and comes to this screen. When it comes to this screen, an sms is sent to the user's phone and I have to receive the incoming sms on this screen. The codes I got from the internet above work very well, but as I said, they are made on a single screen and are not compose codes.

How can I adapt these codes to my own compose codes please help?